# set additional data for highcharts stacked column series

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to set additional data (set of ids) for *each* stacked element on the column?

I need to get these set of ids on the click of the each stacked element..

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [20, 30, 40]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [50, 60, 60]}
    });
```

example, I need to associate **ids {2,3,5} to element 20, ids {4,6} to 30, ids {1,9} to 40...**.and get these ids back on the click of stacked element on the column. Any approaches are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Also I need ids of all the points on the y-axis on click of x-axis label text. Is there any way to this on $('.highcharts-xaxis-labels text').click(function (event) {});

Comment: pvi - you should accept @Paweł 's answer...

Answer (score 1):

Change your format data to something like this:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [{
            y: 20,
            ids: [2, 3, 5],
        }, {
           y: 30,
           ids: [4, 6]
        }, {
           y: 40,
           ids: [1, 9]
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [50, 60, 60]
    }]
});
```

To get `ids` of clicked point simply use `point.events.click` [callback](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.point.events.click).

Comment: This worked. I can able to get the ids associated with each point. I also need ids of all the points on the click of x-axis label text. Can you please update the answer how to implement this on $('.highcharts-xaxis-labels text').click

Comment: With your solution it would be harder. I suggest to use [custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) plugin instead, where you have access to clicked object. Note: I won't write all code for you.. ;)